# how to convert varchar to datetime format in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to convert varchar to date time 
This is what I have now, and it is not working for me. I always get the have value

```
STR_TO_DATE(REPLACE(LEFT('5/16/2011 20:14 PM', LOCATE('M' , '5/16/2011 20:14 PM')-3), '/',','),'%m-%d-%Y %T')
```

This following code returns 5,16,2011 20:14

```
select REPLACE(LEFT('5/16/2011 20:14 PM', LOCATE('M' , '5/16/2011 20:14 PM')-3), '/',',')
```

my current output is emply string now. it should be 2011-05-16 20:14:00

How can i get this to work?

thanks

Comment: `20:14 PM` is redundant.  Why is your time like that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If your varchar is like this:

```
5/16/2011 20:14 PM
```

you can convert it to datetime using this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('5/16/2011 20:14 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i')
```

or this to format it like you want:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('5/16/2011 20:14 PM', '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')
```

Comment: The final value that i am looking for is 2011-05-16 20:14:00 your returns 5/16/2011 8:14:00 PM

Comment: what if my column value is only time, like: 04:00

Comment: that should be `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'`, note the `%i` instead of `%m`