# SQL: aggregation from different tables with different date formats

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, format

Working with the following sql tables:

table: fiscal

```
DateID   | date                  | fiscal_year | fiscal_week 
20170101   2017-01-01 00:00:00.0   2017          2017 WK 01
20170102   2017-01-02 00:00:00.0   2017          2017 WK 01
```

table: email_info

```
email_id | email_name    | email_subjectline
123        New_Year_2017   Welcome the new year!
345        Reminder        Don't forget
```

table: sent_info

```
email_id | sent_date
123      | 1/1/2017 8:58:39 PM
345      | 1/2/2017 6:33:39 AM
```

table: click_info

```
recipient | email_id | click_date
XYZ         123         1/7/2017 4:25:27 PM
ABC         123         1/5/2017 3:13:56 AM
CDF         345         1/6/2017 2:20:16 AM
ABC         345         1/14/2017 3:33:25 AM
```

Obviously there are many rows in each table.

The joining between the email tables is straightforward.

```
SELECT * 
FROM email_info
JOIN sent_info
ON sent_info.email_id = email_info.email_id
JOIN click_info
ON click_info.email_id = email_info.email_id
```

I am struggling with the following:

- how to get all dates into the same format? ( I don't need the times,
  only the day)
- how to join the fiscal table so I can filter by fiscal week for example
- how to count all clicks for an email for 7 days after the sent date (this cannot be hard-coded by dates, but must be dynamic)

This is the output I am looking for (filtered by fiscal week = 2017 WK 01):

```
email_id | email_name    | sent_date |  fiscal_week | Clicks
123        New_year_2017   1/1/2017     2017 WK 01     2
345        Reminder        1/2/2017     2017 WK 01     1
```

*Please note that the last click in the click_info table example was not counted, because it was beyond the 7 days after sent date.

** DateID is an integer and sent_date and click_date are strings/varchar

Comment: which data type are the column  dateId, sent_date , sent_date  ?

Comment: dateid is integer and sent_date and click_date are string/varchar

Comment: string varchar with date and time  ..  and integer with the number equalt  to  a date ..?   ?????   i'm sorry but  is not  a reasonable way for design  a database ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming that  dateId is varchar and the others are datetime should be

```
select a.email_id, a.email_name, date(b.sent_date), c.fiscal_week, count(d.click_date)
from email_info a 
inner join fiscal c on  str_to_date(c.dateID, '%Y%m%d') = date(b.sent_date)
inner join  sent_info b on b.email_id = c.email_id
inner join click_info d on d.email_id = b.email_id 
    and date(d.click_date) between date(b.sent_date) and DATEADD(week,1,date(b.sent_date))
group by  a.email_id, a.email_name, date(b.sent_date), c.fiscal_week
```

PS *do the fact the query struct is defined  if you have other format you can convert properly and change the single piece*

Comment: unfortunately, the other dates are not datetime, they are strings/varchar

Comment: then you can simply convert the string into the datetime using str_to_date  and for the integer you can simply cast as a string ...  should not is difficult ..  the structure of the query is already build so you can only the single piece ..

Comment: I am very new to cast, would you mind showing me, how you would do that? Thank you very much for your help

Comment: cast int to string  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15368753/cast-int-to-varchar   and str_to_date  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15396058/how-to-convert-varchar-to-datetime-format-in-mysql

Comment: how do get all dates into the same format? ( I don't need the times, only the day) DATE({0})

Comment: @AndreyBelykh   you are not the OP   owner  .. what's happen ?  ..  if you have a question post  your question coorectly document as   new post

Comment: Thank you very much @scaisEdge - testing it now